# I am triggering build from the teamcity , version are imported to UCD automatically but the auto deployment is not happening

Tags: udeploy

I am triggering build from the teamcity , version are imported to UCD automatically but the auto deployment is not happening in the udeploy , can some one help how to to auto deployment in UCD by triggering build in teacmity pleaseee???

Answer (score 0):

Hope so, your issue is resolved now but still if you are looking for the precise answer then I would suggest you look into the below uDeploy REST API documentation.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.2.0/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/rest_cli_applicationprocessrequest_request_put.html

In order to trigger the deployment in UCD using any component process, you must have to create the application process first which will be configured with the desired component process.

Then, You can write any custom script that will be able to execute the REST API as shown in the aforementioned documentation in order to trigger the deployment automatically in UCD from Teamcity or any other tools.

Answer (score -1):

go to the applications tab, click on the application name and move to configuration tab. check the "Run a process after the version is created" and then retry the build.